# Creating a shopping list option on a website for you to write your shopping list in

Tags: javascript, html, session

Would it possible to create an option on a e-commerce website that allows the user to write what products they're looking for so they don't forget. Something that possibly drops down if you click it, and using sessions remembers on each page?

Would this be done by JavaScript or could it be done by HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 local storage would be accessible through Javascript.

You would also want to have server-side storage of the list to support older browsers and to allow users to save their list to their account, then bring the list up on another device.

For example, I make the list on my desktop computer, then switch to my tablet to show another member of the household who is in another room.  In this case, the local storage from the desktop would not be available on the tablet, so would need to be fetched through an AJAX call, or loaded with the initial page load.